# Understanding あるところ when used in a past-tense sentence

Tags: grammar, words

In

> 昔あるところにおじいさんとおばあさんが住んでいました

Why isn't ある in the past tense (since we're talking a place that existed in the past)? Would the sentence still be grammatical if it was?